# Power BI Matrix Custom Sorting

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, report, data-visualization, dashboard

Hi every one i have the below matrix, and i need to have custom sorting,

1. By Cover Type (which is in rows)
2. Year (which is in Columns): the sorting should be based on year -1 instead of current year ex: 2019 instead of 2020
3. Brokerage: (which is in Values) sort Descending

[image]

can any one advise me how to do it .

Appreciate your assistance
Best regards,
Georges

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom columns which represents your sorting, if it is not possible with the raw data.

In the query editor for example add a custom column:

Your last year flag:

```
 Last Year Flag = Date.IsInPreviousYear([YourDateColumn])
```

Just include everything you need for the sort order:

```
 Cover Type Sort Order = if [Cover Type] = "A" then 1 
                         else if [Cover Type] = "J" then 2 
                         else if [Borkerage] = "G" then 3 
                         else 4
```

Afterwards you can click on the three dots in the top right and sort by this custom column.

Comment: hello , sorry for the late reply, but i am still not able to apply your instructions, can you be more specific. Year is in column , and brokerage is in value, i want to sort descending for the value of brokerage in Year -1 column . thanks in advance

Comment: What I wanted to say is: That what you want is not possible in the matrix. You cant sort by value at year -1 if your matrix looks like this. Power BI is laking some functionality here. In the top right of your visual (the three dots) that is your only custom sort option. So like I said above, if you want this sort order you will need to create a custom column with your sort order, put this column also in the matrix and sort by it.